# Cannot read property 'count' of undefined Express API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

When i call Create Option api it is working fine but when i call list api get error: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined Express (Node + MongoDB) API.here is my Option Controller File code.
i have Log DB.ProductDoption ,getting result but count function not working.

```js
const _ = require('lodash');
const Joi = require('joi');

exports.create = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const validateSchema = Joi.object().keys({
      name: Joi.string().required(),
      key: Joi.string().required(),
      description: Joi.string().allow(['', null]).optional(),
      options: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
        key: Joi.string().required(),
        displayText: Joi.string().required()
      })).required()
    });
    const validate = Joi.validate(req.body, validateSchema);
    if (validate.error) {
      return next(PopulateResponse.validationError(validate.error));
    }

    const key = Helper.String.createAlias(req.body.key);
    console.log(DB.ProductDoption);
    const count = await DB.ProductDoption.count({ key });
    if (count || validate.value.key === '_custom') {
      return next(PopulateResponse.error({
        message: 'Please add unique name for key'
      }));
    }

    const option = new DB.ProductDoption(validate.value);
    await option.save();
    res.locals.option = option;
    return next();
  } catch (e) {
    return next(e);

  }
};


exports.list = async (req, res, next) => {
  const page = Math.max(0, req.query.page - 1) || 0; // using a zero-based page index for use with skip()
  const take = parseInt(req.query.take, 10) || 10;

  try {
    const query = Helper.App.populateDbQuery(req.query, {
      text: ['name', 'key', 'description']
    });

    const sort = Helper.App.populateDBSort(req.query);
    const count = await DB.ProductDoption.count(query);
    const items = await DB.ProductDoption.find(query)
      .collation({ locale: 'en' })
      .sort(sort).skip(page * take)
      .limit(take)
      .exec();

    res.locals.optionList = {
      count,
      items
    };
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
};
```

Comment: seems like ```DB.ProductDoption``` doesn't exist

Comment: if doesn't exist my insert data function working fine

Comment: Where are you inserting? your code doesn't suggest there is any inserting. Either way before ```const sort = Helper.App.populateDBSort(req.query)``` run the following code ```console.log(DB.ProductDoption)``` and double check the output.

Comment: i have updated code check it , here create function working fine but list function getting this error

Comment: Provide full error stack trace, the stack trace will tell you line of code where issue is going on.

Comment: error in this line const count = await DB.ProductDoption.count(query);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

collection.count is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. Use Collection.countDocuments or Collection.estimatedDocumentCount instead